# Provider mock error: Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm very new to jasmine and I got some issue trying to mock a provider.
I have a provider that looks like :

```
 angular.module('myApp')
 .factory('MyService', function ($resource) {

return {
  actionResource : function(projectId, actionId){
    var url = 'blablabla';
    if(actionId){
        url += "/"+actionId;
    }


    return $resource(url, {}, {
      'create': {
        method: 'POST'
      }
    });
  },
};
});
```

I have a controller using this factory

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, MyService, $state) {

```
$scope.addAction = function(){
    MyService.actionResource($scope.projectId).create($scope.action,
                                   function(){
                                       $state.go('somewhere', {});
                                   });
};

  });
```

and I'd really like to test this controller, at the moment I'm doing something like :

```
'use strict';

describe('[test] [controller] - myCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

 //mock creation
  beforeEach(
       module(function($provide) {
         $provide.factory('MyService', function() {

           var actionResource = function(projectId, actionId){
                                    var create = function(){return {}};
                                    return {create:create};
                                }


           return {actionResource:actionResource}
          }



         )})
       );



  var $httpBackend, $rootScope, myController, mockMyService;

  var scope = {};

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($injector, $rootScope, MyService) {


       var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
       scope=$rootScope.$new();
       mockMyService = MyService;


       spyOn(mockPilotageService, 'actionResource').and.callThrough();
       spyOn(mockPilotageService.actionResource(), 'create');

       createController = function() {
       return $controller("myCtrl", {$scope:scope, myService:mockMyService});
     };
   }));




  it('myCtrl - addAction() calls actionRessource.create() method', function() {
      createController();
  scope.addAction();
  expect(mockMyService).toBeDefined();
  expect(mockMyService.actionResource).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockMyService.actionResource().create).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });


});
```

and I'm getting this error :

> Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.
>               at /Users/*****/myController.spec.js:86

So it's able to spy on mockMyService.actionResource but not on mockMyService.actionResource().create. I can't understand why

any help would be more than welcome

thanks

Comment: have you tried putting '.and.callThrough()' after your spyOn for create?

Comment: Yes I did, no more luck.